# How to backfill the nulls with a value from another column 1 row ahead?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have records that look like this:

[image]

I am trying to backfill every null with the value in the effective_date column that is 1 row ahead. So for the first null, the value should be: `2022-09-05 02:32:29.940416`. How can I do this?

this is on redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IIF(expiry_date IS NULL, LAG(effective_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY effective_date DESC), expiry_date)
```

If effective_date is not consecutive throughout your dataset, then you would need to create an index column.

```
IIF(expiry_date IS NULL, LAG(effective_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY idx_col DESC), expiry_date)
```

Comment: should it be lead instead of lag?

Comment: And where does this go?

Comment: The LEAD function is used to access data from subsequent rows.
The LAG function is used to access data from previous rows.
You could use either one. If you want LEAD instead, you would then change ORDER BY effective_date ASC (instead of DESC).

Comment: it would go in the SELECT statement:
SELECT IIF(expiry_date IS NULL, LAG(effective_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY effective_date DESC), expiry_date) AS new_expiry_date_column